# Oozie coordinator configuration properties

Tags: apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

Configuration properties specified in coordinator job are not seen in workflow's param tags.

Coordinator:

```
<action>
    <workflow>
      <app-path>${workflowRoot}/report_action.xml</app-path>
      <configuration>
        <property>
         <name>OUTPUT_COORD</name>
         <value>${workflowRoot}/2014_05_01</value>
        </property>
      </configuration>
    </workflow>
  </action>
```

Workflow:

```
<action name="pig-node">
      <pig>
...
        <param>OUTPUT=${OUTPUT_COORD}</param> 
      </pig>
      <ok to="end"/>
      <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

What I get is 'EL_ERROR', variable OUTPUT_COORD cannot be resolved.

What could be the problem?

Comment: how you run it ? seem that it's not running from the coordinator ....

Comment: yes, you are rgiht. I was running workflow not coordinator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax wise, variables are well defined in Coordinator and Workflow. As Mzf pointed out, it seems you are running workflow directly. Instead you need to run coordinator which will eventually run workflow (as defined) and pass the value of OUTPUT_COORD to Workflow from Coordinator as well.

Comment: You can run oozie workflow without triggering by a co-ordinator. Define a properties file and define all the variables needed for the workflow in the properties file. 
With the properties file you can run the oozie workflow.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_oozie/apache_oozie_property_file.htm